# How to disable ranges with makeindex, instead showing list of pages

Tags: imakeidx

I'm using `imakeidx` to create an index, together with `makedindex`.  In case, an entry is indexed in several consecutive pages, a range is shown (e.g., 5-7).

How to disable such ranges and show a list of page numbers instead (5, 6, 7)?

- makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2019]
- imakeidx.sty    2016/10/15 v1.3e

Comment: `\makeindex[options=-r]` should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MakeIndex man page

```
-r  Disable implicit page range formation; page ranges  must  be  created  by
    using  explicit  range operators; see SPECIAL EFFECTS below.  By default,
    three or more successive pages are automatically abbreviated as  a  range
    (e.g. 1--5).
```

Thus calling

```
\makeindex[options=-r,<other settings>]
```

will do. In case you already use `options`, just add `-r`.

Comment: Thanks. Too easy, though. I thought I had read the docs in full